Por que a palavra "da" não leva acento?
Por que a palavra "da" não leva acento? É uma oxítona terminada em "a" e leva acento em certas situações, como: "Me dá o copo!"
Em outras situações, ela não leva acento, como: "Ela é da praia."
Qual a razão por trás disso? Eu imagino que seja porque a palavra é uma abreviação da palavra daquele/daquela mas talvez seja só uma exceção da língua portuguesa...

Da é a contração de "de" com "a", tal qual italiano possui a contração "della"  (di+la), uma contração diferente de daquela (de+aquela).
A questão da acentuação em monossílabas é justificada, em fontes digitais, pela tonicidade ou atonicidade da palavra. Os monossílabos tônicos (dó, nó, dá, pó, lá, é, sé, pô, quê, nós) levam acentos, os átonos não (do, no, da, e, se, que, nos), como se registra aqui.
A distinção no caso do 'e' e 'o' é clara, o acento agudo marca uma vogal aberta, o circunflexo uma fechada, e verifica-se que, nos sem acento, a vogal se altera na maioria dos dialetos, no caso do 'e' para 'i' ('de' se pronuncia 'di'), do 'o' para 'u' ('do' se pronuncia 'du').
No caso do 'a' a distinção já não é clara pois não há 'a' tradicionalmente fechado, só aberto (vide: nota nos comentários). Por isso, sugiro que nesse caso somente se memorizem os casos, que não são muitos, pois não há tantas monossílabas terminadas em 'a'. De qualquer modo, a sugestão pra memória que faço é que 'da' não se acentua pois o próprio artigo 'a' não leva acento.

Estranho esse voto negativo. A quem votou: lembre-se de, quando possível, deixar um comentário com sugestões construtivas de melhora.

Uma nota: o 'a' tradicionalmente é só aberto, mas em português tecnicamente há o 'a' fechado, por exemplo na palavra amanhã /amɐˈɲɐ̃/, somente o primeiro 'a' é aberto.

Verdade, talvez fosse o caso de adicionar que se fala de monossilábicos, caso contrário há um monte de contraexemplos, especialmente nasais (ama, cano, etc.).

@stafusa Fi-lo. Todavia, em casos específicos, há o 'a' fechado em monossílabos: interjeição 'dã', empréstimo 'fã', adjetivo feminino 'sã', os homónimos 'cã', nome 'rã'.

dá vem do verbo dar
eu dou
tu dás
ele/ela dá
nós damos
vós dais
eles/elas dão
Veja mais sobre "Conjugação do verbo dar" em: https://brasilescola.uol.com.br/gramatica/conjugacao-do-verbo-dar.htm
dá e dás levam acento para não se confundirem com os artigos definidos com a preposição de:
de+a = da, da menina ou de + as, das meninas
de=preposição a ou as=artículo definido, quando junto=da ou das
Me dá o copo. Verbo
Ela vem da praia. de + artigo definido a = da

Home  Novo Acordo Ortográfico
Acento diferencial
O acento diferencial é usado em casos específicos para evitar ambiguidade na escrita. Ele ocorre em palavras que possuem a mesma
grafia, mas significados diferentes.
O acento diferencial é o acento gráfico que diferencia pares de
palavras com mesma grafia, mas significados diferentes. É usado em
casos bem específicos, havendo alteração em seu uso com o Acordo
Ortográfico, vigente no Brasil desde 2009.


Acento diferencial

Veja o artigo acima.

dá e dás levam acento para não se confundir Não acredito ser este o principal motivo pelo qual estas palavras sejam acentuadas. Se puder fundamentar sua afirmação, peço que o faça.

Acento diferencial
O acento diferencial é usado em casos específicos para evitar ambiguidade na escrita. Ele ocorre em palavras que possuem a mesma grafia, mas significados diferentes. Você quer ir por esse caminho? Não adianta pôr a culpa em mim! https://mundoeducacao.uol.com.br/acordo-ortografico/o-acento-diferencial.htm O nome têcnico é acento diferencial. Você deveria tira o voto negativo.

Agora tenho dois votos positivos. Credo. Que batalha.

Não precisa surtar. Isso poderia estar na sua resposta desde o início.

@GuiImamura É mas não estava e portanto eu tinha razão. A outra resposta não tem nenhuma referência e recebeu um voto positivo! Eu comparto o que sei e nem sempre dou uma referência.

Há sim uma referência, basta ler novamente, com atenção desta vez. O meu voto negativo, aliás, é pela má formatação.

[correção] É mais. //Má formatação não tem nada a ver com conteúdo.

Não importa, respostas devem ser bem formatadas.
